# 5e multi-classing with a wizard level 1 and a druid level 1

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, multi-classing, druid

I just got to level 2 and I'm a Wizard. I decided to multiclass right away instead of leveling my Wizard to level 2 because I couldn't decide which school of magic to choose.

My questions are:

- How many Druid Cantrips do I know for multiclassing into Druid?
- How many Druid level 1 spells do I choose?

Comment: Please answer in answers, not comments.

Answer (score 6):

From the PHB, page 164:

> ***Spells Known and Prepared.*** You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class.

So for the purposes of spells known and prepared, as far as the Druid class is concerned, you are just a level 1 Druid. That being the case, you know 2 Druid cantrips. As a Druid, you know all the spells from the Druid spell list. Finally, as a level 1 Druid, you can prepare a number of spells equal to 1 + your Wisdom modifier every day.

Note that your spell slots are given in the table on page 165 for multiclass spellcasters. As a Druid 1/Wizard 1, you have 3 1st-level spell slots.